# Где найти список кодов регионов php-geo библиотеки sypexgeo?

Tags: php

Взял задачу по переадресации на поддомены сайта в зависимости от географического местоположения посетителя сайта, которое определяется по IP.
Для реализации взял библиотеку sypexgeo. В целом разобрался, но вот мне нужно сделать переадресацию с IP адресов Чеченской республики, а вот где мне взять её код? Я сам из СПБ, мой регион определяется как RU-SPB. Ищу у них в документации и не виду кодов регионов...

Если ли где нибудь этот список, или как эти коды вытащить из файла, я попробовал его в блокноте открыть, он видимо зашифрованный, поиском ничего не удалось в нём найти.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:RU